# Repeating Sequence extraction from a R list / data column

Tags: r, substring

I have a sequence of event time-stamps based on which i have created event process flow strings in R as below :

1. A->B->C->D->E
2. A->C->D->E
3. B->C->D
4. A->E

etc...

I have 50 such process flow combinations. I want to list out each unique transition available in the process flow like below:

1. A->B
2. A->C
3. A->E
4. B->C
5. C->D

etc..

I could not figure out how to do this in R. Any guidance/solution will be highly helpful

Thanks.

Comment: Your expected output is unpredictable, but if you want to break them into individual steps, you could do it with `s <- strsplit('A->B->C->D->E', '->')[[1]] ; sapply(seq_along(s[-1]), function(x){paste(s[x], s[x+1], sep = '->')})`

Comment: Your solution helped. I will tweak it to suit  my code flow. thanks

Comment: Oh, I see what you want now. Edited, where `s` is a vector of flow strings: `s <- strsplit(s, '->') ; unique(unlist(lapply(s, function(x){sapply(seq_along(x[-1]), function(y){paste(x[y], x[y+1], sep = '->')})})))` `sort` if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @alistaire, split the incoming string on `->`, then record the number of elements in each sequence.

```
t <- strsplit(s, "->", fixed=TRUE)
len <- lengths(t)
```

Now, unlist `t` and use the cumulative sum of the lengths to drop the last or first element to get 'from' and 'to' nodes

```
u <- unlist(t)
clen = cumsum(len)
from <- u[-clen]
to <- u[-(1 + c(0, clen[-length(clen)]))]
```

paste `from` and `to` together, find the unique values, and sort

```
sort(unique(paste(from, to, sep="->")))
```

As a single function

```
f0 <- function(s) {
    t <- strsplit(s, "->", fixed=TRUE)
    clen <- cumsum(lengths(t))

    u <- unlist(t)
    from <- u[-clen]
    to <- u[-(1 + c(0, clen[-length(clen)]))]
    sort(unique(paste(from, to, sep="->")))
}
```

For your sample

```
s <- c("A->B->C->D->E",
       "A->C->D->E",
       "B->C->D",
       "A->E")
```

The output is

```
> f0(s)
[1] "A->B" "A->C" "A->E" "B->C" "C->D" "D->E"
```

which enumerates all observed single-step transitions, over the entire data set. Is that what you want?

@alistaire's solution, generalized to handle several strings

```
f1 <- function(s) {
    t <- strsplit(s, "->", fixed=TRUE)
    res <- lapply(t, function(s) {
        sapply(seq_along(s[-1]), function(x) {
            paste(s[x], s[x+1], sep = '->')
        })
    })
    sort(unique(unlist(res)))
}
```

A simple test for identity and benchmarking is

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> identical(f0(s), f1(s))
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark(f0(s), f1(s))
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval cld
 f0(s)  45.379  47.010  48.62282  47.6240  48.4005 120.063   100  a 
 f1(s) 179.509 182.168 184.41779 182.9585 183.7985 234.607   100   b
```

For large data sets `f0()` will be much faster.